# Is there a way where the allure-results folder does not remove the old xmls? Please advice

Tags: allure

On running test cases in parallel using `Spock`, everytime *allure-results* folder is deleting the earlier xmls.

Is there a way where the *allure-results* folder does not remove the old xmls?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what language your using, but in ruby rspec you would do:

```
  config.include AllureRSpec::Adaptor
  AllureRSpec.configure do |config|
    config.clean_dir = false
  end
```